# What are these terminologies mean regarding Marching Square?

Tags: algorithms

Kindly refer to  [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares).

[image]

I only need the 2D version of the algorithm. I understand the 2D version of the algorithm and [I implemented it](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/248645/199333).

However, this article uses the following terminologies which I am confused about:

1. Iso-value
2. Iso-line
3. Iso-band = the filled area between two isolines
4. Iso-level

What do they actually mean?

Comment: "Isolines" are defined in the linked article: "lines following a single data level" ("iso" is a prefix of Greek origin meaning "equal"). So presumably "iso-value" means "the value that the isoline is determined by". The description of the algorithm seems to be just fine if you replace "isovalue" by "the value you chose".

Comment: @GregMartin, what is "*single data level*"?

Comment: A single value that the data could take.